Как получить матрицы костей из gltf файла и костевая анимация в gltf
Я начал разбираться с анимациями в gltf файле, используя библиотеку tinygltf, и у меня появились несколько вопросов на которые я не могу найти ответ:

Я не знаю как получить матрицы костей которые нужно интерполировать
Я не знаю что делать с массивом weights в tinygltf::Node
Я знаю что массив joints в tinygltf::Skin ссылается на tinygltf::Accessor, но я не знаю что с этим нужно делать.

